# Replace developer persistence.xml with the production one while building a war deployment in Intellij

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, deployment, intellij-idea, war

I am deploying a spring-mvc application which uses JPA to access MySQL database. Access information is stored in persistence.xml, while creating a deployment war file I would like to replace developer persistence with the production one.

I tried to copy the production xml directly into the deployment folder (intellij settings), but it has no effect a dev. copy is always deployed.

How do I configure IDE to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If your project is mavenised, then you can use the maven-war-plugin or maven-resources-plugin to customise the resources used to build the war, and the ide should honour these plugins.

Comment: I am using Intellij 12, tried to add deployment config file to artifacts, but they are ignored